# How to call script with python in the same directory with subprocesses?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to open a script from the same directory with subprocesses with python 3 in Windows 10,(I Am the administrator) and using pycharm, however I'm getting the following errors for any alternative solution I try:

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\CobraCommander\\PycharmProjects\\BlackBox', 'Avalon.py'])  # The above "BlackBox" it's the directory for both files.
```

with this I get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

If I try instead:

```
subprocess.call(['python Avalon.py'])
```

with this I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

so I tried:

```
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\CobraCommander\\PycharmProjects\\BlackBox\\Avalon.py'])
```

with this I get the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I also tried to run as administrator from terminal and get same error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Kindly before trying to mark as duplicate, note that I have already read the other posts for the errors as well as subprocesses.

Can anybody advise how to lunch this script in python from another script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `python` before your script so instead of

`subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\CobraCommander\\PycharmProjects\\BlackBox\\Avalon.py'])`

use

`subprocess.call(['python', 'C:\\Users\\CobraCommander\\PycharmProjects\\BlackBox\\Avalon.py'])`

Make sure your PYTHONPATH environment variable is set.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply `cwd` argument to set the working directory:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

```py
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.run(r'touch d:\test.txt')
    p = subprocess.run(r'ls -la test.txt', cwd=r'd:\\', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(p.stdout.decode())
```

output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 abdusco 197609 0 Jul 18 13:32 test.txt
```